# Presenting image picker using TapGesture on UIImageView

Tags: swift3, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I have a View with an `UIImageView` that I want to be 'selectable' so that the user can pick a new image.

The function for picking the new image is in the Controller.

### Question

How do I call the `myDatasourceController.handleTap()` function by pressing the `ImageView`, so that the image picker is presented?

This is an example of my current setup

### View

```
class myView: UICollectionViewCell {

    lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        iv.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myDatasourceController.handleTap)))
        return iv
    }()
}
```

### Controller

```
class myDatasourceController: UICollectionViewController, 
    UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
        UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func handleTap(){

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true

        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        // logic for picking the image

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }    
}
```

---

This setup currently throws the error

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9163d493f0

which has led me to try various combinations of

```
handleTap(_:)
handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecogniser)
/// etc
```

but I can't get any of them to work. How should I be constructing my View, Controller, and the interaction between them to present the image picker?

Comment: You should use `Delegate` pattern rather than directly referencing your VC in your view class. Similar to `UITableView`. Create a protocol, and your view will inform when the tap occurs to this protocol. Now your VC should implement this delegate and will get the event when imageview is tapped.

Comment: @Aks - YES! thanks for the pointer. I've posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to the solution is to implement a protocol / delegate, as suggested by @Akis

I've uploaded the full project to [my github account](https://github.com/tospig/ImagePickerDelegate/tree/master/ImagePickerDelegate/ButtonPress). The key code is copied here.

#### View Controller

```
protocol ImagePickerDelegate: class {
    func loadImagePicker()
}

class HomeViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, ImagePickerDelegate {

    let cellId = "cellId"

    func loadImagePicker(){
        print(" -- image picker -- ")
        // load image picker

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true

        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        // get the image
        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

        if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
        }else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
        }

        if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
            //doSomethingWithTheImage(image: selectedImage)
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .black
        collectionView?.register(HomeView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! HomeView
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }
}
```

#### View

```
class HomeView: UICollectionViewCell {

    // break retain cycle with weak var
    weak var delegate: ImagePickerDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)      
        setupViews()
    }

    lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "kuang-si-falls-waterfall-water-laos-50588.jpg")
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(loadImagePicker))
        iv.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        return iv
    }()

    func loadImagePicker() {
        delegate?.loadImagePicker()
        print(" imagePickerProtocol called ")
     }

    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = .white

        addSubview(profileImageView)

        profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Like this

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RegisterViewController. handleTap(gesture:)))

func handleTap(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // if the tapped view is a UIImageView then set it to imageview
    if (gesture.view as? UIImageView) != nil {
        print("Image Tapped")
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!

        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: this still gives the `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc025d47ff0'` error

Comment: make sure you write the code like this way only :-"handleTap(gesture:))"

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
myDatasourceController.handleTap()
```

In your code :

```
iv.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myDatasourceController.handleTap())))
```

Comment: This fails to build with the error:  `Instance member 'handleTap' cannot be used on type 'MyDatasourceController'`